# When switching from reach/router to react-router, how do you set basename?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am migrating from reach/router to react-router v6 and I have a set of routes like this

```
<Router basename={appPath}>
  <Dashboard path="/" />}
  <DashboardMessages path="messages"/>
  <DashboardTasks path="tasks" />
  <AboutPage path="about" />
</Router>
```

but in the new style in react-router at v6, it looks like:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
    <Route
      path="messages"
      element={<DashboardMessages />}
    />
    <Route path="tasks" element={<DashboardTasks />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="about" element={<AboutPage />} />
</Routes>
```

but routes doesn't take a basename. How can I set this?

---

update: In the docs it says:

> "The  prop may be used to make all routes and links
> in your app relative to a "base" portion of the URL pathname that they
> all share. "

But if you do something like this:

```
<Router basename={appPath}>
 <Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
    <Route
      path="messages"
      element={<DashboardMessages />}
    />
    <Route path="tasks" element={<DashboardTasks />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="about" element={<AboutPage />} />
 </Routes>
<Router>
```

Typescript complains that:

```
 Type '{ children: Element; basename: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'RouterProps': location, navigator
```

I am guessing I can get location from useLocation(), but there doesn't seem to be a way to get navigator.

Comment: I'm not getting the same error as you. Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @TheTisiboth Are you trying on `react-router-dom` v6? Check the [Router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#router) interface/type declaration in the docs, `location` and `navigator` are required props.

Comment: Yes, look at it here : https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-danilo-956mz?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Ahhh I see, I'm not using the Router component, but the BrowserRouter instead, that's where the confusion come from I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of the higher-level routers that manage the navigation context.

- [BrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#browserrouter)
- [HashRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#hashrouter)
- [NativeRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#nativerouter)
- [MemoryRouter](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#memoryrouter)

Example:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

<BrowserRouter basename={appPath}>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
      <Route
        path="messages"
        element={<DashboardMessages />}
      />
      <Route path="tasks" element={<DashboardTasks />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="about" element={<AboutPage />} />
  </Routes>
<BrowserRouter>
```

The [`Router`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#router) is the low-level interface shared by the all the other routers.